# Running tests with 'ng e2e' is throwing 'Invalid host header'

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, protractor, cucumber

I am executing protractor tests by executing `ng e2e` command, after running server on **Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/**

Then tests executes on localhost:4200 successfully, but when url changes to 'http://demo-qa.companyname.com:4200/' in 'protractor protractor.conf.js' as baseUrl, test failing while hitting the url with error 'Invalid Host error'

The same url when I type manually on browser it is working though. Not sure what I am missing,

I had also tried by providing protractor config parameter to pick config file after ng e2e command, final command looks like `ng e2e --protractorConfig=e2e/protractor.conf.js` , yet no luck. Any suggestions, on what I am missing.?

Comment: you can try 
ng e2e --no-serve --base-href=http://demo-qa.companyname.com:4200/

Comment: @arpitsharma: I tried and failed. I am assuming here, 'baseUrl' in conf file should still exists. That is in both the places one at conf.js  `baseUrl:'http://demo-qa.companyname.com:4200'` and other at package.json file as `"e2e": "ng e2e --no-serve --base-href=http://demo-qa.companyname.com:4200/"`

Comment: @FayazMd Were you able to resolve this issue ? Facing same with Cypress now